# Seleccionar datos por fecha mínima

Tags: oracle, base-de-datos

Tengo un grupo de datos de varias personas de las cuales debo extraer la información dependiendo de la la primera fecha de inicio, tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
 SELECT p.CODIGO,TRIM(p.APELLIDO1),p.APELLIDO2,TRIM(p.NOMBRE1)||' '||TRIM(e.NOMBRE2),dt.NUMDETALLE,MIN(dt.FECHAINICIO)

    FROM PERSONA p, VINCULACION vn, VINDETALLE dt

    WHERE p.CODIGO = vn.CODIGO AND vn.NUMVIN = dt.NUMVIN AND dt.FECHAINICIO IS NOT NULL AND dt.NVLCONTRATACION = 1  AND vn.VINESTADO = 1

    GROUP BY p.CODIGO,p.APELLIDO1,p.APELLIDO2,p.NOMBRE1,p.NOMBRE2,dt.NUMDETALLE,dt.FECHAINICIO
```

que me arroja esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y la información que necesito seria algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hay mas columnas de debo anexar a la consulta pero básicamente los datos que necesito son los que están en la fecha mas antigua de cada persona, espero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo tienes que hacer con una sub-consulta. No pude probar el código por no tener la tabla, pero si da error me lo informas.

```
SELECT p.CODIGO,TRIM(p.APELLIDO1),p.APELLIDO2,TRIM(p.NOMBRE1)||' '||TRIM(e.NOMBRE2),dt.NUMDETALLE,MIN(dt.FECHAINICIO)

FROM PERSONA p, VINCULACION vn, VINDETALLE dt

WHERE p.CODIGO = vn.CODIGO AND vn.NUMVIN = dt.NUMVIN AND dt.FECHAINICIO IS NOT NULL AND dt.NVLCONTRATACION = 1  AND vn.VINESTADO = 1
and dt.FECHAINICIO=(select MIN(dt2.FECHAINICIO) from VINDETALLE dt2 where vn.NUMVIN = dt2.NUMVIN AND dt2.FECHAINICIO IS NOT NULL AND dt2.NVLCONTRATACION = 1  )

GROUP BY p.CODIGO,p.APELLIDO1,p.APELLIDO2,p.NOMBRE1,p.NOMBRE2,dt.NUMDETALLE,dt.FECHAINICIO
```

Comment: muchas gracias ariel, me ha servido mucho tu respuesta,efectivamente es la solucion, te hago otra consulta, tengo que capturar muchos mas datos de la tabla VINDETALLE dt ¿todos los campos que tengan que ver con esa tabla deben ser nuevamente llamados con la dt2?, de nuevo mil gracias

Comment: No, solo tenes que obtener la Min(fechaIngreso) y en el where poner los filtros para que solo traiga una fila. Si así como esta funciona como esperabas, no modifiques la sub-consulta, y agrega en la consulta principal todos los datos que necesites. Recorda de marcar la respuesta como correcta.